# How can I get my game to show up in the Games Explorer on Windows?

Tags: windows, deployment

I want to create an installer for a game which allows for an icon to be put in the Games Explorer for Vista and Windows 7.

I have created the [GDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then built the script for project and obtained the .h, .gdf and .rc files. But I can't compile (using Visual Studio 2010) the .rc file into an executable to be used after that in order to create the installer. I get the following error after I set the executable path:

> "Could not load file or assembly'Microsoft.VisualStudio.HpcDebugger.Impl, Version 10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublickKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you've seen this, but in case you haven't: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417682(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It seems like there may be a file included in the .rc that isn't on your machine maybe from the Win SDK.

Comment: in the solution explorer of your project are all of the references loaded ? (expand the References section of your project and look for ! marked items) ... what language / framework is this game in? C#? Managed C++ ? VB ? (each language can have its own idioms). The file or assembly referenced is a performance debugger. don't know if that helps or not.

Comment: The previous post marked as answer doesn't solve the problem, at least in my case. I get the same error message and have repaired/re-installed VS2010 and also used SP1. Problem remained. Wish I could get around this somehow. -- Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not related to inserting a link in the Games Explorer. It's likely a install error. This issue has been [reported to Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/690472/vs-2010-ultimate-performance-explorer-missing-file), and received some attention, but wasn't followed up on. Microsoft has a recommendation for solving this issue:

> The file that is
> reported as missing should have been installed into the correct
> location when Visual Studio installed. Please try one of the following
> actions:
>
> - From the "Add or remove programs" menu repair your installation of Visual Studio 2010
> - Install SP1 from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691

As for the question, [George Duckett](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8110/how-can-i-get-my-game-to-show-up-in-the-games-explorer-on-windows#comment28520_8110) likely provided the most [important link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) already. Which contains step-by-step instructions for getting your game to show up in the windows games explorer.